# In Linux, how do I get this Arduino library to work

Tags: arduino-uno, library, timers, linux

In Linux Fedora 20 Arduino I want to use the Timer library from [here](https://github.com/JChristensen/Timer), from which  I have downloaded the folder `Timer-master.zip`, but, when I try to import it, I get the Arduino message that it cannot be imported because its name includes characters other than plain ACSII letters and numbers. I have tried copying the file to `Timermaster.zip` and importing that instead, but still got exactly the same failure message.

Please, how do I get out of this impasse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's causing the problem is that the folder name inside the zip has a hyphen in it, just extract the folder from this zip and rename it to `timer` instead of `timer-master`. I just imported it on Fedora 20.

Comment: #'itchyzombie, Thanks for that prompt and excellent answer. I have done that and, as you say, it works. A day wasted in frustrating floundering, but a nice end result